Measure to indicate Top 5 market share and company of interest
I am comparing my product's market share with that of top 5 in the industry in 1 column chart. However, I'm unable to do this and need some help. I have tried using the Top N filter on PowerBI, but this only gives me Top 5 but I cant bring my company's results in if it isnt in top 5. Is there any way I can do this?
What I have:
Table of Market Values by Company. e.g.



Company Name
Market Cap




Pears
2.1T


Oranges
1T


Bananas
0.9T


Grapes
0.9T


Watermelon
0.8T


........
0.7T


........
0.6T


Mangoes(my company)
0.2T



What I need is to display the Top 5 in the industry(up until Watermelon above) as well as my company (Mangoes) on 1 column chart with market size being the measure of Company Market Cap/Sum of all companies' market cap.
Thank you

UNION(
TOPN(5,...),
FILTER( )   <--- filter for your company here
)

It seems like you'd want an entirely new table, but maybe I'm wrong. See both approaches...
To create a new measure
Add new measure with this Dax Formula:
VAR Top5Fruits = 
    TOPN(
        5, 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            YourData, 
            "Values", 
            YourData[Market Cap]
        ),
        YourData[Market Cap],
        DESC
    )
VAR Mangoes = 
    FILTER(
        YourData, 
        YourData[Company Name] = "Mangoes"
    )
VAR CombinedTable = 
    UNION(
        YourData,
        Mangoes
    )
RETURN
    SUMX(
        CombinedTable, 
        YourData[Market Cap]
    )

New Table Approach
Multiple Steps:

Create a column displaying ranking of all companies based on market cap
Create a column showing true or false if top 5 or your company name
Create a new table that filters old table for only true values displayed in previous step
Hide old table and unneeded columns created in above steps

Example
Starting with This Data Table YourData



Company Name
Market Cap




Pears
2.1


Oranges
1


Bananas
0.91


Grapes
0.9


Watermelon
0.8


NobodayAlpha
0.76


NobadyBravo
0.75


Mangoes
0.73



Add Ranking Column
Dax formula needed:
Rank = RANKX(ALL('YourData'), 'YourData'[Market Cap], , DESC, Dense)

Add Column Displaying TRUE if part of top five OR your company name (Mangoes).
Dax formula needed:
Top5PlusOne = IF(
    'YourData'[Rank] <= 5 || 'YourData'[Company Name] = "Mangoes",
    TRUE(),
    FALSE()
)

End Original Table result

Create New Data Table Filtering on True Values in Fourth Col
UserData = FILTER(YourData,YourData[Top5PlusOne]=true)


Hide Old Table And Helper Columns

Final Data From User View

